# link extraction using HtmlAgilityPack and c#

Tags: c#, html, search-engine, html-agility-pack

i want to extract google result links
My code works it does extract links, but these links are not what i expected to be extracted.
My program would extract links inside the "a href" tag but all links in search result are not Appropriate links , ads link , googles link are also included
what should i do?

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Search
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // load snippet
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlSnippet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] ResultsBuffer = new byte[8192];
        string SearchResults = "http://google.com/search?q=" + txtKeyWords.Text.Trim();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SearchResults);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = resStream.Read(ResultsBuffer, 0, ResultsBuffer.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResultsBuffer, 0, count);
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }

        while (count > 0);
        string sbb = sb.ToString();

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
        html.LoadHtml(sbb);
        HtmlNode doc = html.DocumentNode;

        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            //HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
     //       if ()
            {
                int index = hrefValue.IndexOf("&");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    hrefValue = hrefValue.Substring(0, index);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue.Replace("/url?q=", ""));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

if i want to work with "a href" tag i have to add some condition in If
 
 but i dont know what condition i should use here:

```
if ()
```

someplace i read about extracting cite tag not ahref tag 
 anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the links that are contained in the `cite` elements, simply access their inner text, like:

```
    HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
    var hd = w.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=veverke");

    var cites = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//cite");

    foreach (var cite in cites)
        Console.WriteLine(cite.InnerText);
```

Comment: @ververke Tnx alot. If I want to get the title of each url and descreption of the url just like the google result page , what should I do?

Comment: I am not much familiar with `Xpath`, so I would do it using css instead. To be able to use css selectors with `HtmlAgilityPack`, install the `ScrapySharp` nuget package, add a `using ScrapySharp.Extensions`, and you will have now a `CssSelect` method available at `HtmlNode` objects. Now running `hd.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".rc h3").Select(n => n.InnerText)` should do it.

Comment: tnx a lot . hd.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".rc h3").Select(n => n.InnerText) with this line how i get the title for each URL?